# Column Validation Error

Tags: 2013, column, validation

I am trying to validate a 1 to 5 position column where allowable entries are notstrict text formatted and am getting the following error:

```
formula contains syntax error or is not supported.
```

Trying to validate a column that can contain 1-5 positions:

- Pos 1 contains numbers
- Pos 2 can contain Cap letters, or numbers
- Pos 3 can contain Cap Letters or space
- Pos 4 can contain numbers or a space
- Pos 5 can contain Cap Letters or numbers. E.g. ( must have format of #,##,##C,##C #,#C #,#C #C)

Example of what I have been trying

```
=(LEN(UPC)>0)
+(LEN(UPC)<6)
+((CODE(MID(UPC,1,1))>47)
+(CODE(MID(UPC,1,1))<58)
=2)
,IF(
ISNUMBER(MID(UPC,2,1))
,((CODE(MID(UPC,2,1))>47)
+((CODE(MID(UPC,2,1))<58)
=2))
,((CODE(MID(UPC,2,1))>64)
+((CODE(MID(UPC,2,1))<91)
=2)))
,IF(
(CODE(MID(UPC,3,1))=20),
,+(CODE(MID(UPC,3,1))=20)
=1)
,((CODE(MID(UPC,3,1))>64)
+((CODE(MID(UPC,3,1))<91)
=2))
,IF(
(CODE(MID(UPC,4,1))=20),
,+(CODE(MID(UPC,4,1))=20)
=1)
,((CODE(MID(UPC,4,1))>64)
+((CODE(MID(UPC,4,1))<91)
=2))
,IF(
ISNUMBER(MID(UPC,5,1))
,((CODE(MID(UPC,5,1))>47)
+((CODE(MID(UPC,5,1))<58)
=2))
,((CODE(MID(UPC,5,1))>64)
+((CODE(MID(UPC,5,1))<91)
=2)))
```

Comment: mid is not a supported operator

Answer (score 1):

Eric wrote in the comments:

> MID is not supported

Then I have had a very special SP since I started working with SP2003

`=MID("Eric Alexander",6,4)` returns `Alex` for me.

*Eric is most likely confused with `SUBSTR` that does not exist in SP*

---

All the Functions that do work in SP: https://365CSI.nl/functionlist

Yosko specifically needs to look at the AND/OR **Functions** to replace all those additions he now uses to fake boolean logic

```
((  CODE(MID(UPC,1,1))>47) + (CODE(MID(UPC,1,1))<58)  =2  )
```

then becomes

```
AND(  CODE(MID(UPC,1,1))>47 , CODE(MID(UPC,1,1))<58  )
```

Good thing is to built your Formulas step by step,
you use `CODE(MID(UPC,3,1))` **4** times.

Put it in its own Calculated Column 'Asc3'

So you can do

,IF(
(Asc3=20)
**, ,+**(Asc3=20)
=1)
,((Asc3>64)
+((Asc3<91)
=2))

Hey! there is your failing syntax:

## ,+

### Thinking in Strings instead of ASCII codes

Here is what you get when you think **"A Letter is a Letter when it occurs in a String"**

Had to dust of my old CalcMaster tool I used on projects where we did loads of **maintainable** Formulas..

I start with 2 Strings of Capitals and Digits and then built it step by step

Once everything works the CalcMaster tool merges all Formulas together (Blue)

And your Formula *should be*

```
=AND(
 ISNUMBER(FIND(MID(MyValue,1,1),"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"))
,ISNUMBER(FIND(MID(MyValue,2,1),"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"&"1234567890"))
,ISNUMBER(FIND(MID(MyValue,3,1),"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"&" "))
,ISNUMBER(FIND(MID(MyValue,4,1),"1234567890"&" "))
,ISNUMBER(FIND(MID(MyValue,5,1),"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" &"1234567890")))
```

#### Outputs

[image]

#### (Private tool) Building Calculated Formulas

*screenshots shows a mix of Text/Boolean, SP is very lenient on types*

[image]

#### Merged Formulas:

[image]